# GSON - десериализация объекта в объекте

Tags: java, json, gson

Есть *JSON* такого вида:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "meta": {
        "count": 1
    },
    "data": {
        "36791942": {
            "last_battle_time": 1435324597, //...
        }
    }
}
```

Т.е., объект `36791942` находится внутри `data`. Как правильно десериализировать с помощью *GSON* и получить значение, к примеру, `last_battle_time`?

Comment: Не уверен что такую структуру получиться десериализировать. так как 36791942 должно быть переменной. а такой переменной быть не может.

Как вариант написать кастомный обработчик, в котором кусок кода  "36791942": { "last_battle_time": 1435324597, //... } обработать как текст

Comment: А можно ли получить значение непосредственно `last_battle_time`?

Comment: Вам обязательно использовать GSON? Если нет, то можно попробовать через Jackson сериализовать в HashMap, ключом тогда будет просто строка.

Comment: @zzashpaupat а где библиотеку Jackson найти? На codehaus просит авторизацию.

Comment: @Yalikesifulei
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core

Comment: @ConstantinePl каким должен быть класс для meta? `public class MetaClass`?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо создать класс java , который будет повторять структуру JSON

```
class JsonClass
{
    public String status;
    public MetaClass meta;
    public DataClass data;
}
```

теперь необходимо создать класс для **meta** и **data**. С **meta** все просто, а вот для **data** надо написать собственный обработчик:

```
public class DataGsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<DataClass>
{
    @Override
    public DataClass deserialize( final JsonElement arg0, final Type arg1, final JsonDeserializationContext arg2 ) throws JsonParseException
    {
        return /* тут нужно обычными операциями работы со строками  произвести какое то действие */
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Каким должен быть класс для meta? `public class MetaClass {}`?

Comment: public class MetaClass 
{
public int count;
}

Comment: А что должно быть на месте arg0, arg1 и arg2? И что именно нужно делать со строками?